# Where is Appcelerator LeftNavButton RightNavButton Documentation?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

**Where is the Appcelerator LeftNavButton RightNavButton documentation?**

I cannot find any documentation for the LeftNavButton or RightNavButton anywhere in the [latest documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium)!

I believe this should be included as property and corresponding method of the [Titanium.UI.Window](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window) object.

I can see the method (and property) in the documentation search (see attached image) but nowhere in the actual documentation. I checked page filters and tried using another browser.

[image]

Comment: Yeah... docs are broken...

Answer (score 1):

I contacted the Appcelerator team who confirmed the docs were not displaying  correctly. Appcelerator made a modification on 9/6/16 which resolved the problem.

You can now [see the documentation here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-leftNavButton).

Comment: This makes sense -- I noticed the other day that the Window.close event was not in the documentation.  It's back now.  I thought I was losing my mind!